# How to include the error term as an explanatory variable in a lm() model when the errors are auto-correlated?

Tags: r, regression, predictive-models, error

I am wondering if there is a way to include the error term as an explanatory variable in a lm() model when the errors are auto-correlated.

For example,  I have a model that gives errors that has a pattern in it, and I wish to model that pattern too so that it is built in as a part of the original model. I should be able to use the new model to prediction.

```
Mod <- lm (response ~ pred1 + pred2, data=inputdata)
```

Is there a method/package that already does that ?

Comment: The error term simply contains all the factors that you haven't accounted for in the model. I don't think you can model it explicitly as an explanatory variable. To the best of my knowledge, the only thing you can do it think of any parameters that you may have excluded from the model and include them. If you include the correct parameters (all those parameters which influence the independent variable), the pattern in your residuals will disappear. Hope that helps

Comment: One method that deals with autocorrelated errors (assuming that's what you mean by "errors that has a pattern") is the setting of ARIMA time series models with external regressors (ARIMAX). If the pattern is other than autocorrelation you may be omitting some relevant variables in the model, as pointed by @Mike. The function  `stats::arima` can be used to fit ARIMAX models. Questions related to the usage of this functon would be best addressed through [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/).